# Finding a Node on a Double Linked List Using a Single Pointer

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am facing a double linked list question which goes as follows:

Let there be a double linked list (with at least 2 nodes) and a pointer, P, that points on some node that is on the list, we'll call it I0. Let there also be a node on that list, we'll call it I1, with value v. In addition, let m be the "distance" between node I0 and node I1, BUT m is not given to us as a variable.

I am trying to find an algorithm that WITHOUT using ANY other pointer except for P, will find the node I1 (P is pointing initially at I0). That algorithm has to work in Theta(m).

Comment: That's the tricky part, you have to search both ways but not exceed the m upper bound. I tried advancing forward one time, then backwards twice, then forward three steps, then backwards four steps and so on until I find the node. Problem is, that I have to use a loop inside of a loop and that causes the algorithm to exceed the linear limit of it.

Comment: Some more information would be useful: May the link pointers in the list be modified during the search? Does the list need to stay intact after the algorithm finishes? As a double linked list contains quite some redundancy, I think it is possible by "destroying" the list and later fixing it once the node/direction is found.

Comment: @mihi yes, the original list should stay intact after the algorithm is finished, however if you know a solution that doesn't keep the original list I'd be glad to see it,

Comment: After some discussion with other students I think your initial solution is correct. No matter how long your list is, your solution will always find the element in time proportionate to M. So therefore it would be a correct solution! :) (I didn't figure this out, an other student did..)

Comment: solution that destroys the list (in pseudocode): `while(p.val != v) {if (p.left != null && p.left.val == v) p = p.left; else if (p.right != null &&p.right.val == v) p=p.right else {if (p.left != null) p.left = p.left.left; if (p.right != null) p.right = p.right.right; }}` - it should be possible to fix up the list after that (as the back pointers will eventually point back to original `p`, but that is left as an exercise to the reader :)